# How can I pass values to paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I have an array of 100 random ints. I want to create a bar graphic from them. I know how to create a single rectangle in a frame but without passing values.

This is the draw class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class draw extends JPanel
{
    public void drawing() {

        repaint();
    }

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(100, 150, 12, 3);
    }
}
```

I want to replace the values in g.fillRect(100,150,12,3) with my random int values. But since i call repaint() from main to call paintComponent, i cant pass values to paintComponent. How do i do it? if its impossible, what alternatives do i have?

Comment: Why not put these values in a class field?

Comment: The main issue here is that you yourself do not explicitly call paintComponent, the swing framework does it for you. Thus even if you could pass arguments to it, it would be pointless. You should instead either have paintComponent request for values using a function call, or have the values previously defined in the class as instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by introducing fields and intitialize then using a constructors, setters, or both :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Draw extends JPanel {

    int x, y, width, height;
    public Draw(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    void setX(int x) {this.x = x;}

    void setY(int y) {this.y = y;}

    void setWidth(int width) {this.width = width;}

    void setHeight(int height) {this.height = height;}

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I pass values to paintComponent

You can't pass values to `paintComponent()`.

> But since i call repaint() from main to call paintComponent, i cant pass values to paintComponent. How do i do it?

For whatever object you want to customize and draw by yourself, you can create a class for that and have a method like `draw()` to do the painting, for example:

```
//Just a normal class with a draw() method
class BarGraph{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private Color color;

    public BarGraph(int x, int y, int width, int height){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color){
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

Then in your main panel for displaying your customized image:

```
class DrawingSpace extends JPanel{
    private BarGraph barGraph;

    public DrawingSpace(){
        barGraph = new BarGraph(50, 50, 400, 100);
        barGraph.setColor = (Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g){
            barGraph.draw(g);        //draw your own customized object
        }
    }
}
```

So instead of trying to pass values to dictate how paintComponent draws, you can pass/set your values in your own class (in this case, BarGraph class). From the Graphics content, implement how you want it to be painted.

In your paintComponent, simply call the draw method which already has "a set of instructions" for how it should be drawn.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot pass values to `paintComponent` method as parameters because, we are just overriding an existing method which is called by Swing. But we can have an instance variable (`values` in my example) in the class which is accessible inside `paintComponent` method (as suggested in other answers/comments).

I'm putting an example program below since, sometimes examples convey ideas better.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class BarGraph extends JPanel
{
  private static final int GRAPH_HEIGHT = 300;
  private static final int BAR_WIDTH = 50;
  private static final int GAP_BETWEEN_BARS = 20;
  private static final int GRAPH_X_OFFSET = 50;

  private int[] values;

  public BarGraph(int[] values)
  {
    this.values = values;
  }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
      g.fillRect(
          GRAPH_X_OFFSET + (i * (GAP_BETWEEN_BARS + BAR_WIDTH)),
          GRAPH_HEIGHT - values[i],
          BAR_WIDTH,
          values[i]
      );
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int[] graphValues = {100, 150, 50, 250, 200, 75};

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Graph");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new BarGraph(graphValues), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setBounds(300, 200, 600, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```